# Why is the last page number of the bibliography showing in the table of contents instead of the first page of the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

MWE is as follows:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, mathtools,amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rsfso}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,maxbibnames=200,sortcites=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=9cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
    \rule[0.5cm]{15cm}{0.1cm} 
\Huge
    {aaaaa}
    \rule{15cm}{0.1cm}
    \\
    {\normalsize \it{aaaa}} \\
    {\normalsize \it{aaaaa}} \\
    {\normalsize \it{aaaa}} \\
    {\normalsize \it{aaaa}}\\
    \vfill
    
\vspace{5cm}
{\normalsize by} \\
{\normalsize aaa}\\
{\normalsize aaaa}\\
{\normalsize aaaa}\\
{\normalsize  aaaa}\\
\rule{15cm}{0.1cm}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{main1}
\chapter{main2}

\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Well it wont show in this MWE since there inst any citations but for example, if I were to have three pages in the bibliography starting from page 10 and ending on page 12, in the table of contents, instead of showing "bibliography....... 10" it shows "bibliography....... 12". Any reason why and how can I fix this?

Comment: @egreg I had a look, I cant figure it out..

Comment: `\printbibliography` prints the entire bibliography.  Afterward, `\addcontentsline` adds that page to your toc.

Comment: @Teepeemm This is understood however my question is how do we adjust it so that the first page of bibliography appears in toc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... how can I fix this?

I suggest you replace

```
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

with

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography
```

That way, the `\addcontentsline` directive is issued at the start rather than at the end of the bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\printbibliography`'s optional argument to supply a `heading` value that adds the entry to the ToC. You probably want `bibintoc`, but there are other possible values (see pp. 99-100 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

You can and should then get rid of the `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, english=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric, sortcites=true, maxbibnames=200,]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image: ToC with correct page numbers.]